# pdftk path on windows server

Tags: php, pdftk

I have placed pdftk.exe in the windows server folder through filezilla.

I am running following code

```
<?php echo passthru('/usr/bin/pdftk.exe --version'); ?>
```

Nothing happen. How can I use path.

pdftk What I placed in the server folder https://db.tt/E7X2BqEe

In addition my windows server is shared server, not vps.

Comment: Change the path to where `pdftk.exe` is, is that a problem?

Comment: I have run echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; getting like /mnt/stor3-wc2-dfw1/493787/497503/xyz.org/web/content.  now I am using <?php echo passthru('/mnt/stor3-wc2-dfw1/493787/497503/xyz.org/web/content/pdfForm/usr/bin/pdftk.exe --version'); ?> Not working. How can I get absolute path of pdftk. In addion I can access remotely with filezilla.